# Difference between gaussian and log-normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms, normal-distribution

I have a random variable say X that is a Gaussian distributed with mean equal to zero dB. When I convert it into linear domain, i.e from dB to linear, does it imply that the resulting variable is log-normally distributed?And if yes, would the mean of resulting log-normally distributed variable also be zero? I would be thankful if anyone clears my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the resulting distribution has a log-normal distribution. If $X$ is normally distributed, then $e^X$ has a log-normal distribution. Be careful however, your transformation is not just $\exp$, it must be $10^X$ or something like that, according to the definition of dB.

No, the mean of the resulting variable is not zero. It can't be zero as a log-normally distributed random variable is almost surely *positive*. However it's possible to determine its mean as a function of the parameters of the original gaussian distribution.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: I see. Since the mean in my case is defined in dB (0dB), do I need to convert it first into linear domain and then calculate the new mean of the log normally distributed variable based on the formula in the link that you provided?

Comment: Yes, but you'll also need the variance of the original variable.